# How to interpret this Scottish Catholic Register birth/baptism entry?

Tags: birth-records, scotland, parish-register

I've found the entry for an ancestor's birth in the Scottish Catholic Register (1851, Glasgow) and I'm confused what two annotations might mean. I found it on ScotlandsPeople but have searched the site for tips to no avail.

1) The second column describes the legitimacy of the birth but what does a blank space mean? Is there another possibility other than the parents were not married? I happen to know that one parent was Catholic and the other Presbyterian. Would the Catholic church have regarded that as unlawful?

2) Some of the names have an M or a P to the left of them. Thoughts on what that might mean?

[image]